# why code does not giving the right answer it suppose to to create a function that finds the middle item from a list of values

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
def middle_element(lst):
    if len(lst) % 2 == 0:
        midindex1 = int(len(lst) / 2)
        print(midindex1)
        average = (lst[midindex1 - 1] + lst[midindex1]) / 2
        return average

    else:
        midindex2 = int(len(lst) / 2)

        return lst[midindex2]


print(middle_element([5, 2, -10, -4, 4, 5, 8]))
```

Comment: What's wrong about this? The code prints `-4` which is literally the element in the middle of the list.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your code I think you are trying to `implement Median on the list`

[Mean Median Mode Formula](https://www.cuemath.com/mean-median-mode-formula/) <- Link to formula

For median you first need to `sort the list`

**Method 1:**

```
def middle_element(lst):
    lst.sort()   #Sorting the list
    if len(lst) % 2 == 0:
        midindex1 = int(len(lst) / 2)
        print(midindex1)
        average = (lst[midindex1 - 1] + lst[midindex1]) / 2
        return average

    else:
        midindex2 = int(len(lst) / 2)

        return lst[midindex2]


print(middle_element([5, 2, -10, -4, 4, 5, 8]))
```

This will output:

```
4
```

**Method 2:** 
You can use `statistics library`

```
from statistics import mean, mode, median

lst = [5, 2, -10, -4, 4, 5, 8]

print(mean(lst))
print(mode(lst))
print(median(lst))
```

This will output:

```
1.4285714285714286
5
4
```